# TypeORM inserts dates incorrectly - using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typeorm

I have a weird problem with **TypeORM** (v0.2.45) using **Microsoft SQL Server** (mssql v6.3.1)

I have an **Entity** which has columns of type **date** which when inserting data a day is subtracted from the date for example:

```
@Entity("employees")
export class Employees extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    uuid: string;

    @Column({type: 'date'})
    birth_date: Date;

    @Column({type: 'date'})
    entry_date: Date;
}
```

I insert 2022-03-15 (YYYY-MM-DD) and the record is saved in the table as 2022-03-14

It should be noted that I have already carried out the corresponding tests to verify that the date did not mutate before inserting and ultimately the problem comes from the mssql dependency.

Investigating I discovered that there is a problem as described here:

[TypeORM inserts dates incorrectly](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7225)

It has worked for me to change the type to *datetimeoffset* as described below:

```
@Entity("employees")
export class Employees extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    uuid: string;

    @Column({type: 'datetimeoffset'})
    birth_date: Date;

    @Column({type: 'datetimeoffset'})
    entry_date: Date;
}
```

The detail that I have is that when performing the corresponding migrations, the data type of the column will change to *datetimeoffset* and I consider that it is not a good practice.
The other option that seems very *vague* to me is to add that day that is subtracted from the date before inserting it
But both solutions I consider that they are not the most optimal.

**I already updated the TypeORM and MSSQL dependencies and the problem persists**
How could I solve it?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
createBuzonDto.desde = new Date(createBuzonDto.desde.getUTCFullYear(), createBuzonDto.desde.getUTCMonth(), createBuzonDto.desde.getUTCDate())
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**